# Smooth frequency change

Tags: java, android, audio, frequency

I'm trying to continuously play a sound, whichs frequency should be changed smoothley. For example, my AudioTrack is currently playing on a frequency of 100 Hz, and the new frequency is 1000 Hz. Then I don't want the frequency to jump, but to smoothley adapt to the changes. My current code looks like this:

```
int buffSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,
                                           AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                                           AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRate,
                                       AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                                       AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffSize,
                                       AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
short samples[] = new short[buffSize];
int amp = 10000;
double twopi = 8. * Math.atan(1.);
double phase = 0.0;
audioTrack.play();
while (playing)
{
    double newFrequency = getFrequency();
    for (int i = 0; i < buffSize; i++)
    {
        samples[i] = (short) (amp * Math.sin(phase));
        phase += twopi * newFrequency / sampleRate;
    }
    audioTrack.write(samples, 0, buffSize);
}
audioTrack.stop();
audioTrack.release();
```

This, of course, is run in the background. My sampleRate is automatically set to the lowest possible value:

```
private int getMinSampleRate()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
        if (AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(i, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT) > 0)
            return i;

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [low-pass filter](http://justinvoss.com/2011/11/07/smoothing-data-with-low-pass-filters/) to smooth the transition. Here's another [example](http://phrogz.net/js/framerate-independent-low-pass-filter.html).

```
double currentFrequency = getFrequency();
double smoothing  = 10;   // calculate based on your sample rate and desired time delta for the change
while (playing)
{
    double newFrequency = getFrequency();
    for (int i = 0; i < buffSize; i++)
    {
        // because you are filling the buffer, deltaTime will be a constant: the time between samples
        currentFrequency += deltaTime * ( newFrequency - currentFrequency ) / smoothing;
        samples[i] = (short) (amp * Math.sin(phase));
        phase += twopi * currentFrequency / sampleRate;
    }
    audioTrack.write(samples, 0, buffSize);
}
```

Keep a historical record of the frequency and slowly change it towards you new value using incremental steps, based on the delta.  For large deltas, the value will change faster at the beginning and then slower near the end.  IIRC, this is called a first-order filter because you aren't controlling the acceleration of the change.  A second order filter will smooth the acceleration.

There are lots of different techniques, check out the filters at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing#Smoothing_algorithms).